Did ancient civilizations believe their gods to be humanoids?
Reading the Wikipedia article on reductio ad absurdum, I read the following:

Criticizing Homer's attribution of human faults to the gods, Xenophanes states that humans also believe that the gods' bodies have human form. But if horses and oxen could draw, they would draw the gods with horse and ox bodies.[9] The gods cannot have both forms, so this is a contradiction. Therefore, the attribution of other human characteristics to the gods, such as human faults, is also false.

Despite this, it seems ancient Greek gods were commonly depicted as humanoids, presumably because  Xenophanes of Colophon was not the authority on how to depict gods.
Did ancient Greeks believe that their gods had a "physical" form that is humanoid? Did they believe that their gods had a form at all? This would be in contrast of their graphical depictions of the gods, that could have been made in spite of their belief, for example because we only ever managed to identify graphical depictions of humanoids as being of their gods.
What about other ancient religions? While I'm interested with the Greek pantheon in particular, I'm curious about all religions that may be of interest to this subject.
Hoisting my comment:
Are there any texts that exist that reference a god being, say, the literal wind, or do texts consistently consider gods to be things with heads, arms and legs, beyond when they're actively transformed into animals or concepts as an explicitly temporary thing that's happening in the story being told? I guess what I'm trying to get at is "was the 'canonical' form of their gods humanoid"?
I'm well aware ancient Greek mythology frequently depicts gods in various forms for story purposes, but it is my understanding that this mostly happens within a set story, and does not become the actual form the god has in the collective imaginary. Any counterexample would be an answer to what I'm asking.

Seems like you've answered your own question twice. First by pointing out the distinction between "depicting" and a more difficult to evaluate "believing" and second by pointing out that Xenophon did not enforce artistic convention.  What additional research have you done? Where have you looked?  Is there any reason to believe that the "average" Greek had a clear vision of the God's substance/appearance? Or does Greek mythology clearly tell us that the Greek gods appearance was determined by the God at the moment. God's regularly transform into Bulls and Swans and beams of light, etc.

depict vs believe: yes, that's the point. are there any text that exist that reference a god being, say, the literal wind, or do texts consistently consider gods to be things with heads, arms and legs, beyond when they're actively transformed into animals?

Is there any reason to believe that the "average" Greek had a clear vision of the God's substance/appearance? -> effectively that's what i'm trying to ask.


Please move the comment into the question.  OP should almost never comment on their own question, but should edit the question to clarify the issues.

Well, Boreas, the Greek god of the north wind, storms, etc. was depicted as a humanoid. Multiple examples in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boreas_(god)

I think we can field this, but it's also on topic for Mythology.Stackexchange.

One of the recommended answers sheds interesting light on early depictions of the gods https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/44060/why-did-ancient-greek-religious-monument-herms-have-genitalia?rq=1

Still haven't address the point that the Greeks represented their gods both as human and as abstract forces, and as showers of gold/swans/bulls, etc.     I think the question is insufficiently precise to be answered.\

Given the life-and-death role we play in the lives of horses, oxen, and other domestic beasts - how can we be so sure that they wouldn't ascribe human form to their gods?

@MCW: I'm well aware ancient greek mythology frequently depicts gods in various forms for story purposes, but it is my understanding that this mostly happens within a set story, and does not become the actual form the god has in the collective imaginary. If you have counter examples, they would be an answer to what i'm asking.

Can you explain whence you get your understanding that "[this] does not become the actual form the god has in the collective imaginary"? Given the representation of gods in statuary and vase paintings, I'm having a hard time seeing where this question is coming from. I'm not even sure what it means for a god to "literally be the wind". I think some clarification (as in: rethinking and editing the question) would be helpful here.

Can you say which ancient civilizations you're thinking of, other than Greece? Either way, I suggest neither you nor anyone else could justify the cited passage, 'Criticizing Homer… is also false.'
Would you care to try that yourself? Can you paraphrase the passage?

@RobbieGoodwin: My question stands with, for example, ancient Rome, ancient Egypt as well as ancient India, really any religion from antiquity where the answer is nuanced. I feel like including the citation was a mistake. It's just the starting point that made me wonder how people other than Xenophanes, who was clearly very opinionated, thought.

Does that mean you don't want to, or simply can't paraphrase the passage?
I hope everyone here knows the Greeks and Romans saw their gods as broadly 'human' but that's not the same as 'humanoid' - a usage I've never noticed in 60 years of listening. Are you suggesting divine powers alone made Greek or Roman deities 'humanoid'?
I hope everyone here knows ancient Egypt and India saw their gods as 'humanoid, which is very different.
Almost separately, how is this about History more than, say Religion, Philosophy or even simple Language?

Different people believed different things. At one extreme, the Epicurean school of thought had it that the gods were not only distant and uninvolved in human affairs, but even that they were "abstract" in form. The exact contours of this belief are the subject of scholarly debate but it's clear that something of this kind was typical of Epicureans.
From the pro-Epicurean side, Lucretius says (De rerum natura 5:146-155) that the gods are incapable of touching or being touched, and that their bodies are rarefied or spectral (tenues). Whatever we "see" of them is only an illusionary image projected onto our own minds (simulacra ... in mentes hominum divinae nuntia formae, 6:80-81). As humans we tend to receive a humanoid image, or the human form may be so strongly associated with reason that  it is the "natural" idea-shape of a reasoning being.
We also find opponents such as Cicero having trouble with this idea (though his version of the teachings is possibly a bit of a caricature or straw-man). He understands Epicureanism to say that the gods have only a quasi-body and quasi-blood (De natura deorum 1:49ff), still a human-like form, but one essentially free from volition or emotion. Cicero finds it ridiculous to identify that kind of abstract god with the Graeco-Roman deities, who can't possibly be described as uncaring non-actors; and the idea that they have human body parts but don't use them is absurd to him (1:123). He also objects to an alternative of identifying the gods with the area of their dominion (e.g. Neptune with the sea itself), as nobody who eats corn imagines that they are actually eating the god Ceres (3:41). He appears to prefer a view where the customary gods are accepted and venerated with their unique characteristics, and aren't assimilated into a philosophical abstraction.
Cicero also acknowledges a common belief (i.e. held by the vulgus) in the gods not only having limbs, but physically making use of bows, arrows, spears, etc. (1:101). He himself presents a view where it is meaningful to say that one god has grey eyes and another blue, but where the gods aren't limited to acting in ordinary physical ways. And he thinks that only the ignorant could believe in animal-divinities, or in heroes like Hercules or Romulus being deified and entering heaven like new citizens being added to the rolls (quasi novos et adscripticios cives in caelum, 3:39), as he thinks there is an insuperable difference in kind between mortals and the immortal gods. While this is again polemical, it does seem plausible that non-philosophers would have a fairly more literal understanding of the gods.
At a meta level, the vitality of this sort of debate shows that there were many possible views about exactly what was the situation with divine bodies. I would also add the caveat that the entire line of inquiry about belief is orthogonal to religious practice. People would make offerings at shrines regardless of their metaphysical speculations. These religious duties were generally considered to be vitally important, compared to any particular view someone might take about "doctrine".

Excellent; this is the answer I wanted to give, but you have more scholarship and have written better than I could have.

Fascinating. You are right that this is mroe about doctrine rather than belief but i lacked the vocabulary. thank you for your answer!

My latin is rusty, but isn't "quasi novos et adscripticios cives in caelum" rather "like new registered citizens in the sky" ?

@Evargalo yes, he's comparing deification to the administrative process of becoming a Roman citizen, and saying that it's silly to imagine that one could be admitted into godhood in the same way
